# nmpro - mailto opens up outlook and new tab - but i dont want new window in browser to open.

Tags: html, mailto, edmx

I am using below code in nmpro to make edm. But when i click this link in my outlook it open up mailto in outlook (which is good thats what i want) but it also opens up a new tab in browser with link http://www.mycompanyname.coma/nmpro/inc/rdr.asp?0___-1___145___125(last numbers are random)

```
 <a id="privatedinner" href="mailto:rsvpau@test.com?Subject=Kisumé%20Private%20Dinner" >                                                                                                                    <img src="http://mycommpanyname.com.au/nmpro/assets/b2.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="float: none; margin: 0px;" />                                                                                                                </a>
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it, it was due to tracking was enabled in nmpro so i just turned it off and it works fine.

Thanks for help though.